# $ \int_0^\pi f (x) \sin x=\int_0^\pi f (x) \cos x=0$.Prove that $f (x) $ has two roots in the interval $(0, \pi).$

Tags: calculus

f is a continuous function. $ \int_0^\pi f (x) \sin x=\int_0^\pi f (x) \cos x=0 $.Prove that $f (x)$  has two roots in the interval $(0 ,\pi)$

Look that $\sin x>0$ over the whole interval and thus to make the integral $0$, we must have $f(x)<0$ at some point.But if we get a root, we may transform the origin to the root and then use the sign changing property of $\cos x$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Prove that $f(x)$ has 2 roots in $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that $ f(x) $ has at least two real roots in $ (0,\pi) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247385/prove-that-fx-has-at-least-two-real-roots-in-0-pi)

Comment: Note: that's not a question, it's a demand. Less likely to get results in general. :)