# Proof that $f(x)$ has two roots over $(0, \pi)$ at least! And other developing question.

Tags: calculus

Question 1:
Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function over $[0, \pi]$. Then the definite integration of $f(x)\sin{x}$ and $f(x)\cos{x}$ over $[0, \pi]$ are all 0.

> Prove that $f(x)$ has at least two zeros over $(0,\pi)$.

It is easy to see that $f(x)$ one root over $(0, \pi)$ But it is difficult to show $f(x)$ has at least two roots over $(0, \pi)$.

Question 2:

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function over $[a, b]$. Then the definite integration of $f(x)$ and $f(x)g(x)$ over $[a, b]$ are all 0. And g'(x)~=0(over $(a, b)$).

> Prove that $f(x)$ has at least two zeros over $(a,b)$.

Comment: It is a copy of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247385/ !

Comment: Question 2 is not a copy of  math.stackexchange.com/questions/247385 ! – kotomord.