# If $\int_0^\pi{f(\theta)\cos\theta}=\int_0^\pi{f(\theta)\sin\theta}$, prove that $f$ has two zeroes in $(0,\pi)$

Tags: contest-math

I read a Putnam question recently. I am having trouble remembering which year it was, but it was probably from before the 1950's

> Let $f\in[0,\pi]$ be a continuous function. If $$\int_0^\pi{f(\theta)\cos\theta \;{\rm d}\theta}=\int_0^\pi{f(\theta)\sin\theta\; {\rm d}\theta}$$ prove that $f$ has two zeroes in $(0,\pi)$

Consider the function $f(\theta)=e^{-\theta}$. It satisfies the condition given above, which can be seen through integration by parts, and does not have any zeroes. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are quite right. I expect you misremembered the question.

Comment: There is currently no $d$ in your integrals. Does the question read $f(\theta)d\cos(\theta)$ or $f(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta$?

Comment: With the condition $\int_0^\pi{f(\theta)\cos\theta}=\int_0^\pi{f(\theta)\sin\theta} \mathbf{ = 0}$ it is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247385 .

Comment: @MartinR- Thanks. I'm sure now that I misremembered the question.