# If $\int_0^\pi f(t) \sin(t)dt =\int_0^\pi f(t) \cos(t)dt = 0$, then $f(x)=0$ admits two solutions

Tags: integration, analysis

> Let $f\colon [0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.  If $\int^{\pi}_{0}f (t) \sin(t)dt =\int^{\pi}_{0} f (t) \cos(t)dt = 0$, then $f(x)=0$ admits two solutions in $[0,\pi]$

I try to show if $f(x)>0$ and then get the contradiction but I failed to prove that, so maybe can someone help me with that? thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence.  We can't have $f(x)>0$ on $[0,\pi]$ for then $f(x)\sin x>0$ on $(0,\pi)$ and $\int_0^\pi f(t)\sin t\, \mathrm{d}t >0$  Similarly, we can't have $f(x)<0$ on $[0,\pi]$.  Is this the contradiction you're speaking of?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247385/42969

Comment: @MartinR and another https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645891/given-int-0-pi-f-theta-cos-theta-d-theta-int-0-pi-f-theta-sin?noredirect=1&lq=1 although the answer was deleted

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: The same answer was posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646196/42969. Unfortunately, it is wrong.